# Excel formula to count number of lines (not necessarily rows) in all non-blank cells in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula to count how many lines are in non-blank cells in a column. For the image below, I would like the formula to return 11.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
=COUNTA(V:V)+COUNTIF(V:V, "*"&CHAR(10)&"*")
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`=COUNTA(A:A)`
Assuming the column is A, if it's a different column change `A:A` to whatever it is.

Comment: I believe a counta has to be adjusted by the cells that have two dates.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Jeeped is correct--I need to essentially count the number of dates in the column, and some cells have multiple dates.